# Applying the count function within the case function

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am relatively new to SQL and am trying to apply the case function within a view.
While I understand the fundamentals of it, I am having difficulty applying it in the way that I need.

I have 3 columns ApplicationID, ServerName and ServerShared? (true/false).

Each application can have many servers associated to it, while each server only has 1 server type.

I would like to use case to create a further field which can take three values dependent upon whether the values of ServerShared related to an application are all True = Shared, False = Non-shared, Both True and False = Partially shared.

My thoughts were using count function within the case function to set statements where:

- if 'count true > 0 and count false > 0' then  ServerShared? =
  partially if 'count true > 0' and 'count false = 0'  then
  ServerShared = true and vice versa.

I believe the above logic a way of achieving my result, yet I would appreciate help in both how to structure this within a case statement and any wisdom if there is a better way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Due to the fact you use SSMS you use SQL-Server, right?

Comment: I've added the correct tags to your question.

Comment: What datatype is the `ServerShared` column?

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, this should do the trick. Maybe you need to add further columns or adapt the logic. But you should get the logic behind.

```
SELECT ServerName, 
    CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(distinct ServerShared) = 2 
        THEN N'Server shared'
    WHEN MIN(ServerShared) = 0
        THEN N'Server not shared'
    WHEN MAX(ServerShared) = 1
        THEN N'Server shared'
    END as ServerShared
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY ServerName
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways to do this problem (super generic answer from non expert :D)

1. less often executed (one off?), slow execution with potential exponential time increases as rows go up:

This is similar to your suggested solution and involves putting other queries in the Select / field list part of the query - this will get executed for every row returned by the main part of the query (bad news generally speaking):

```
select 
    applicationID
    , Case (select count * from table as b where a.applicationid = b.applicationid and shareserver=true)
        WHEN 0 then 'Non-Shared'
        WHEN (select count * from table where a.applicationid = b.applicationid) then 'Shared'
        ELSE 'Partially-Shared' END as ShareType
from 
    tabls as a
```

2. get all your data once then perform just the comparison row by row. this is what i would use by default.. its basically better as far as i know but sometimes can be harder to think through.

*this line is here to fix formatting issue*

```
select 
    a.applicationid
    ,case
      when sharedservers = 0 then 'Non-Shared'
      when totalservers=sharedservers then 'Shared'
      else 'Partially-Shared' END as ShareType
FROM
    (select applicationID, count(*) as TotalServers from table) as a
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (select applicationID, count(*) as SharedServersfrom table where sharedserver = true) as b
          ON a.applicationid=b.applicationid
```

these queries are just written off the top of my head let me know if there are bug :/

note also the two uses of case statement. one with `CASE *value* WHEN *possible value* THEN ..`  and the second way `CASE WHEN *statement that evaluates to boolean* THEN ..`